# How to display different localized app names for different builds of an app?

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I want to show different app names for "dev" and "beta" builds of my app. Now the app name is localized in the InfoPlist.strings file:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName = "localized app name"".
```

I want add a suffix like "beta" to the localized name.

Thanks.